# How to set a folder's name the same with the user account name on CMD?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

I need to create a folder using command line and its name must be the same with the current user's account name.

I mean, if your user account name is "user1", you can create a folder with a name "user1" like this on command line: `mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\user1`

However, I think that I should write a keyword like `%USERPROFILE%` to entitle the folder for different computers and its different users.

So, I will write something `mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%username%` like that for make the folder's name "user1" on a user's PC, "user2" on another user's PC automatically when I run the script. But I don't know what should I write exactly. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you did it?

Comment: You've already wrote it! BTW the user's Account Name is not necessarily the same as that contained within their `%UserProfile%` variable; _(I remember once changing my Account Name, and the fact that the profile directory name no longer matched the account name played havoc with my OCD!_

Comment: Yes, really I've already wrote it, but just noticed it now :) I took a wild guess, and never tried to run this script. Because, "mkdir %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%username%" was just a sensible guess for me, I wasn't expecting to work exactly what I want :) Thanks anyway.

Comment: As a piece of advice, learn to protect variables with unknown content by enclosing them with doublequotes, `MD "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%" 2>NUL`, or preferably precede it with a check that it doesn't already exist, `If Not Exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%\" MD "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%USERNAME%"`.